# Green Video in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, video.js

In my own embedded videos, and on the Video-JS site, I see a bright green screen, like the attached image. Does anyone else see this?

I'm using IE 10 on Windows 7 in VMWare.

[Bright green video bug ie 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja6wH.png)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the VMware turn off hardware acceleration of the graphic card in the VM preferences, then the green screen is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue on a virtual machine (vmware with windows7 on a mac) - I read somewhere that it is likely a video card driver.

Comment: Interesting. do you remember where you read that? If it was only on VMware, I'd be fine with it. So far, I haven't heard any complaints from customers, so that could quite possibly be the case.