# VideoJS in IE10 shows green video

Tags: internet-explorer-10, video.js

has anyone experienced the thing that when you visit the videoJS Homepage in IE10 and the browser does NOT run in compatibility mode, the video renders green? In compatibility mode it works, except for the play button, that doesn't show up properly.

Does anybody has the same effect? Any idea why that happens with an mp4 video?

See secreenshot here: http://www.gojo-agentur.de/js-green.png

Comment: I've posted the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155324/green-video-in-ie-10. Is it happening for you in vmware, or on a standard windows machine?

Comment: Hi, it happens on both, virtual machine and native. Haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Hi, you were right, it happens only on VM when the hardware acceleration of the graphic card in the VM preferences is turned on. Turned off, green screen gone!